# What kind of tasks are a good use of Front Controller's plugins?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Right now I'm learning about Front Controller in ZF. I know that we can extend request flow with Front Controller's plugins by implementing methods : `routerStartup`, `routerShutdown`, `dispatchLoopStartup`, `preDispatch`, `postDispatch`, `dispatchLoopShutdown`.

How do you use Front Controller's plugins?
What are the real world tasks that could be solved using Front Controller's plugins?

Comment: I found the following article helpful when I had the same question myself: http://devzone.zend.com/1224/front-controller-plugins-in-zend-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few examples:

- Access control (e.g. for an 'admin' section/module)
- Setting layouts based on module
- Assigning common variables to the view/layout
- Redirecting old URLs to new equivalents